# How can I make two contact fields responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, responsive

I need to center two fields ("Call Us" and "Our Email") and make them responsive at the same time. They should stack one on top of the other on a small screen. I have inline CSS to position them correctly on a large screen, as is shown in the image, but they don't stack on top of each other on a small screen like they should. I used inline CSS because I couldn't find the CSS file to put the code in. Is it possible to use inline CSS to fix this? If so, this is the inline CSS I have that makes the two fields center properly on a large screen.

```html
<div style="justify-content: center; display:flex; class="row"> 
  <div class="col-xl-4 col-xs-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-12 footer_contact_info">
```

Again, this code does not make the two fields responsive, i.e. it doesn't make them stack on a small screen. Originally there were three fields. The third was "Our Address", but I removed it.

I tried adding inline CSS and was expecting it to be responsive on a small screen but it didn't work.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and edit your question accordingly. After that provide your code in the form of a [repro]. The code part you provided is incomplete and does not show the issue you're describing. Also note, that you should not mix a framework with inline style and that you have a typo (not closing the style attribute with double quotes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are using the Bootstrap framework. The class `row` applies `display: flex`, so your inline style is redundant. You should also use the `justify-content-center` class instead of inline styles.

You have:

```html
<div style="justify-content: center; display:flex; class="row">
```

Should be:

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center">
```

It is redundant to specify the same number of columns at every breakpoint. Use the appropriate class for only the breakpoints where you want the changes to occur, as it will apply to all larger breakpoints.

You have:

```html
<div class="col-xl-4 col-xs-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-12 footer_contact_info">
```

Should be:

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 col-12 footer_contact_info">
```

Since you didn't provide a reproducible example, I am having to guess what your structure is.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-center"> 
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-12 footer_contact_info">Call Us</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-12 footer_contact_info">Our Email</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One tiny extra info for the OP. In Bootstrap you have no XS class as it is the default breakpoint. `col-12` starts at `xs`. @TimR : `col-12` does not have to be declared either as it is the default as well and would also be redundant. `col-sm-4` would be sufficient.

Comment: You're right, `col-12` is the default behavior for a child of `row` due to the `.row>*` ruleset. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score -1):

add `flex-direction:column` to the `style` of your first `div` and if didn't work, just remove `class="row"` from the first `div` and other classes from second `div`

e.g:

```
<div style=" display:flex; flex-direction:column; align-items:center"> 
<div>
```

and by the way, in the column order, the `justify-content` doesn't have any effect, if you want your items be at the center of your page just replace `justify-content` with `align-items` as I have done above but if you don't want it to be at the center just ignore and remove that part.